# Crear un botón Colorido con Material Design en Android

Tags: android, android-layout

¿Cómo se crea un botón elevado `Raised` y colorido sin perder el efecto `Ripple`?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir si asigno un color de fondo al botón automáticamente pierde el efecto ondulado cuando se pulsa, además creo que no hereda las proporciones de material design, lo veo grandote de altura.

La [versión 23.0.0](https://developer.android.com/sdk/support_api_diff/23/changes.html) de [AppCompat](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat), hay cosa nueva, visto en esta entrada [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686250/material-effect-on-button-with-background-color)

```
<Button
  ...
  style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored" />
```

Pero si lo añado no afecta el resultado.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorAccent"
    android:minWidth="180dp"
    android:text="Colored Button"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored" />
```

Comment: Yo también he tenido el mismo problema con el ripple, al final termine por usar alguna librería como https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary o también añadirle a un botón el ripple https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect. Un saludo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 Declara tus estilos en el archivo styles.xml

```
<style name="MyButton" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
     <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/indigo</item>
     <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/pink</item>
</style>
```

2 Agrega el estilo a tu Botón via `android:theme attribute`

```
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"**
    android:theme="@style/MyButton"/>
```

Puedes revisar [Botones personalizados](http://www.materialdoc.com/raised-button/)

Answer (score 0):

Pruebas realizadas partiendo de un proyecto base de android-studio

Partiendo de `styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Diferentes formas para definir botones en material design

**Normal:**

```
<Button
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="normal" />
```

Otra manera, usando definición en style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.RaisedButton">
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button</item>
</style>
```

**Con color de fondo** obtenido de ColorAccent definido al tema

```
<Button
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="accent" />
```

Otra manera, usando definición en style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.RaisedButton">
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored</item>
</style>
```

**Botón con diferente color de fondo**

```
<style name="AppTheme.MyButtonRed">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">#FF0000</item>
</style>
```

**Más personalización** Otras elementos que se pueden personalizar

- Color del fondo: `colorButtonNormal`
- Color del texto: `android:textColor`
- Color del efecto ripple: `colorControlHighlight`

**Ejemplo**

```
<style name="AppTheme.CustomButton">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@android:color/holo_orange_light</item>
</style>
```

Para asignar estilos en un botón:

```
<Button
    ...
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.CustomButton" />
```

Si queremos un `botón raised` con color de fondo `ColorAccent` y texto blanco sin usar estilos, visto en [Medium](https://medium.com/google-developers/choosing-a-button-style-with-purpose-and-intent-35a945e228d3#.2itw316oc).

```
<Button
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Raised"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```